# Impact of continuing with Vue2 even after EOL

Tags: vuejs2

I have few queries related to the EOL of VueJS 2:

- From Wiki link here:[Vue.js - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) , I learn that Vue2 is having EOL in Sep 2023. Is this correct?
- Where can we find the Last minor version of Vue2 i.e 2.7 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/projects/6#card-16117796) ? If we will start using 2.7, how long it would help us to buy some time for migration to vue 3?

We have VueJS2 application and if we fail to migrate to Vue3 due to some reasons before EOL(using migration guide here: [Introduction | Vue.js](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#overview)), What will be the impact?

- Will we stop getting any security updates? OR Can we still expect critical security updates?
- I hope we would still continue development using VueJs2 and npm install would continue to work for dev environment setup? Are there any chances of one or more dependency stop getting downloaded? (for example node sass etc?)
- Are there chances that as the browsers will continue to update to the latest versions and cause some functionality in VueJS 2 stop working and we wouldn't be able to complaint since it’s already EOL?
- I believe since no upgrade will happen to VueJS 2, we wouldn’t be able to expect any support for new features in browsers. Is it correct?

Your response will help us to understand and plan the things much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Will we stop getting any security updates? OR Can we still expect critical security updates?

EOL usually means the same thing on any ecosystem. It stops getting updates to allow moving on to the next thing. It'll still work but it's going to be just like that unless someone continues maintaining it in some way.

> if we fail to migrate to Vue3 due to some reasons before EOL, What will be the impact?

You stop getting updates.

Vue component/libraries/plugin developers might write less Vue 2 code and more Vue 3.

If they wrote a Vue 2 code then use that. If there's none, you write one.

> I hope we would still continue development using VueJs2 and npm install would continue to work for dev environment setup? Are there any chances of one or more dependency stop getting downloaded? (for example node sass etc?)

You can still continue working on it. It will install as long as it is still hosted on npm.

> Are there chances that as the browsers will continue to update to the latest versions and cause some functionality in VueJS 2 stop working and we wouldn't be able to complaint since it’s already EOL?

> I believe since no upgrade will happen to VueJS 2, we wouldn’t be able to expect any support for new features in browsers. Is it correct?

Vue is a library for rendering elements and I don't think it uses or ever will use any browser-specific code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Any idea where can we get the confirmed dates of EOL. I learned they all just suspects somewhere in next year but nothing concrete. Also, is vuejs 2.7 backward compatibility version a reality?